# Raspberry Pi can't use Bluetooth speaker when playing sound from crontab

Tags: bluetooth, cron, raspberry-pi

I have run a timed task on my Raspberry Pi 4 using crontab to play local audio files.

```
00 20 * * * ~/Documents/mp3.py
```

It does work, and the music plays automatically in the background when the time comes.

The problem is that when music is played, the sound comes out of the HDMI speaker, not the Bluetooth speaker. The Bluetooth speaker is connected and working, and when I run this Python code in VS Code and Terminal, the sound is played through the Bluetooth speaker.

I did some reading and added the following to the crontab:

```
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/user_id
```

But it didn't work, when the crontab command was launched, there was still no sound from the Bluetooth speaker.

I don't know what else I can try.

Comment: How are you telling your script to use the Bluetooth speaker? Take a look at the `3.2 connect speaker with cable` section in the following answer: raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/116843/121848

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try again next week.